# Web crawl angular website for elasticsearch indexing

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, web-crawler

Is there a way to index an angular website using the web crawler functionality of elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the web crawler would have to include all the functionality of a browser to work.  Angular universal would be a better solution cause it does all the generation on the server side instead of in the browser.